# Is having an open TCP port dangerous (Mac OSX)?

Tags: security, json-rpc, mac-osx, port-numbers

I was reading [this post on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/3ird55/holy_shit_my_eth_accounts_been_hacked/) where a user got all her ether hacked because she had an open RCP port when deploying a contract.

I just used network utility to run a scan and it turns out I have an open TCP port. Is there any risk involved? I don't even know what a TCP port is for the record.

Comment: Opening a port is always a `threat` you can use firewalls to restrict the connections or use the `--rpccrossdomain` flag to limit the access if youre using `geth`

Comment: @NikhilM a bit of a warning: rpccrossdomain only tells your browser how to set limits, these aren't any sort of firewall limitations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. You have open TCP ports for things like the internet. ie:

80 is the TCP port for all HTTP data

443 is ssl

21 is ftp

22 is sftp

As long as the open port is not the the geth rpc port, then you are fine. You shouldn't arbitrarily open TCP ports, but you likely have a TCP port open for a natural reason.